# Inserting js into iframe not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy jsfiddle's feature on my web page - a user can submit js on a page and it will be executed within an iframe. I ran some test code in jsfiddle and on my page. It works in jsfiddle, but not on my page. Any help is appreciated!

**My page renders the css and html, but the js is not executing (the div background should be blue):**

[image]

**Here is the html in the iframe of the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgagz995/) (which works):**

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .test { display:inline-flex; padding:40px; background-color:#cccccc }
  </style>

  <title></title>         
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)"; 
}//]]>     
</script>          
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test" style="background-color: rgb(21, 160, 249);">test</div>    
</body></html>
```

**Here is the output to my web page:**

```
<html><head><style>
    .test { display:inline-flex; padding:40px; background-color:#cccccc }
</style><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)";
}//]]>
</script></head><body><div class="test">test</div></body></html>
```

**The code that inserts the html, css, and js into the iframe:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var codeContainer = document.querySelector('.executedCode'); //submitted code passed as values in attributes to hidden div on the page in node/express environment
  var html = codeContainer.getAttribute('html'); 
  var css = codeContainer.getAttribute('css');
  var js = codeContainer.getAttribute('js');

  var sandbox = $('.sandboxed');
  sandbox.ready(function() {
    var htmlContainer = document.createElement('div');
    var cssContainer = document.createElement('style');
    var jsContainer = document.createElement('script');
    jsContainer.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    var head = sandbox.contents().find('head');
    var body = sandbox.contents().find('body');
    $(head).append(cssContainer);
    $(head).append(jsContainer);
    $(html).append(htmlContainer);
    $(cssContainer).append('\n\t'+css+'\n');
    $(jsContainer).text('//<![CDATA[\nwindow.onload=function(){\n'+js+'\n}//]]>\n');
    body.prepend(html);
  });

});
```

**window.onload seems to be the breaking point:**

I ran a test by simply inserting an alert. Here's what worked and what didn't.

```
$(jsContainer).text("alert('hi')"); //--works
$(jsContainer).text('//<![CDATA[\nalert("hi");\n//]]>\n'); //-- works
$(jsContainer).text('window.onload=function(){\nalert("hi");\n}\n'); //-- doesn't work
```

Comment: What is the js code that executes the user code within the iframe?

Comment: @jcbp I have edited my post to include this information, you should see it now. Thanks.

Comment: The reason the onload function doesn't fire is because the page already loaded (and the function you're specifying wasn't available at that time)

Comment: thanks @Kerstomaat - btw, if I try to run document.querySelector('.test').style.backgroundColor="rgb(21, 160, 249)";  without the onload function that doesn't work (only the alert does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution occurs on the line `$(jsContainer).text(js)` but the html isn't inserted yet.
You just need to move the line `$(jsContainer).text(js)` after the `body.prepend(html)` (without the `onload` event).